# как в контроллере получить data отправленные из ajax ? laravel

Tags: laravel

отправляем

```html
$.ajax({

               type:'POST',
               url:'/ajaxRequestParameter/'+type,
               data:{
                   "arr":arr, 
                   "product_id":product_id,
                   "category_id":category_id
               },
               success:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
               }

              });
```

а тут как эти data получить?

```
    class ParameterController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //вот так же или в laravel есть свой метод ? 
       $_POST['category_id']; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил вот так можно

```
$name = $request->input('arr');
$name = $request->input('product_id');
$name = $request->input('category_id');
```